# need a solution to converting a CVS file to an arff file

Tags: terminal, weka, arff

I'm a newbie..! and i need to load a csv file to weka so i use  this terminal command

`java -cp /usr/share/java/weka.jar weka.core.converters.CSVLoader newfile.csv > miller.arff`

and i recive some errors like this ...

`Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
---Registering Weka Editors---
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): RmiJdbc.RJDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.mckoi.JDBCDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
java.io.IOException: wrong number of values. Read 8, expected 7, read Token[EOL], line 40140
    at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.errms(ConverterUtils.java:912)
    at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.getInstance(CSVLoader.java:824)
    at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.getDataSet(CSVLoader.java:646)
    at weka.core.converters.AbstractFileLoader.runFileLoader(AbstractFileLoader.java:323)
    at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.main(CSVLoader.java:1041)`

what could be the problem ??

Answer (score 1):

Check line 40140 in newfile.csv. Most likely it contains only 7 values.

Comment: somewhat its working...but have some missing values . anyway thanks..:)